# Is using a WorkManager appropriate for long running network calls

Tags: android

In my app, the user can start a background process that makes long running API calls to the backend. The user will also have the ability to pause the background thread and resume at any point.

If the app restarts, the background process should resume from where it left off. Once the background process has completed, the process should terminate.

Even when the background process is running, if the user hits the device's home button, I still want the background process to keep running. It is not necessary for any UI to be shown while it is running.

Reading up on the Android docs, it would seem that using WorkManager is probably the best choice since my minSdkVersion is 19. Is this true?

Comment: How long are your "long running API calls"? You also use both "background process" and "background thread". Processes != threads, so which were you planning on using?

Comment: The process can run for hours. My app is a single process, so I believe a background thread is what I should be using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The process can run for hours

`WorkManager` work cannot run that long. You could still use `WorkManager` for the scheduling aspect, but then the "work" would need to be starting a foreground service, where the service then does the actual network I/O.

> It is not necessary for any UI to be shown while it is running.

On Android 8.0+, you cannot have something running for hours without UI showing, at least in the form of a `Notification` associated with a foreground service.

Comment: I did a google search and was not able to find anything that indicated the maximum amount of time a WorkManager task can run for. How can I know for certain that a WorkManager cannot run for hours?

Comment: @AndroidDev read this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53734165/android-workmanager-10-minute-thread-timeout-coming-from-somewhere